# zappa docker returns FileNotFoundError No such file or directory: venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages

Tags: python, flask, aws-lambda, aws-serverless, zappa

I am trying to build my Flask app using Zappa and docker ( Serverless with Aws Lambda )

Here is DockerFile:

```
FROM lambci/lambda:build-python3.6

MAINTAINER "Bongo BD" <selim.reza@bongobd.com>

RUN pip3 install -U pip zappa botocore awscli

WORKDIR /home/digital-agency-ms

COPY ./ ./

RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

CMD ["zappa"]
```

Docker build and enter into docker :

```
$ docker build -t zappa .

$ docker run -it zappa /bin/bash
```

Trying to deploy:

```
$ source venv/bin/active
$ aws configure
......
Finally 

$ zappa deploy dev
```

But its getting the following error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '../venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages'
```

Comment: @john is there any solution ?

Comment: I am facing a similar issue, any solution?

Comment: this version has problem , try another one